# MySQL - Store coordinates to avoid duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, mapkit, instagram

I'm trying to build location tag like Instagram...

I select coordinates based on Google Api function `getBounds()`  like this: 

(note: swlat, swlng, nwlat, nwlng = a, b, c, d)

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE
    (a < c AND lat BETWEEN a AND c) OR (c < a AND lat BETWEEN c AND a)
    AND 
    (b < d AND lng BETWEEN b AND d) OR (d < b AND lng BETWEEN d AND b)
```

Before INSERTING coordinates, I  check if the data is present in the table to avoid duplicates . However the problem is **Google Api** and **MapKit**  return different coordinates when you search a specific place.

**Right now** I am storing location's `name` to check for duplicates. Which could work, but maybe there's a better way :)

**So my questions are**:

- how can I store coordinates to avoid as less duplicates as possible. Maybe there's an identifier like "place_id" (in google API) which could work for both cases when using Google Api or MapKit
- do I really need to store location's name, does Instagram use any api to get details about the location?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution really is in how you implement your own database - there is only one location for any given lat/lng co-ordinate.
But you cannot force Google or MapKit to change. therefore you will always be stuck with this discrepancy, and a search on a possible text value name=like '%placename%' will always be low performance and not guaranteed as accurate as you rightly have concern over.
I would therefore suggest you create seperate 'locations' tables for both Google and MapKit and have the user filter them from the GUI.
Also recommended is to index the lat and lng columns for each.

Comment: performance wise, store location's name or use api? the problem is if I use api, then you need to store city and public places in separate rows, because you never know what api gives you... Note: I also want to consider cases when lets say a shop changes its location, then the best way I think is to use `name` to check for changes...  thank you :)